# POST JSON Data from form without AJAX

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to POST data to a REST api without using AJAX.  I want to send the data in JSON format.  I have the following code but am stuck trying to figure out how to convert the input field and POST it to the server.  Here is my code attempt:

```
<form id = "myform" method = "post">
id: <input type = "text" id = "user_id" name = "user_id">   
data: <input type = "text" id = "user_data" name = "user_data">  
<input type = "button" id = "submit" value = "submit" onClick='submitform()'>
</form>

<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >
function submitform()
{   
 var url = '/users/' + $('#user_id').val();
 $('#myform').attr('action', url);

 //
 // I think I can use JSON.stringify({"userdata":$('#user_data').val()}) 
 // to get the data into JSON format but how do I post it using js?  
 //

 $("#myform").submit();
}
```

Comment: insert json into a hidden input.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the onclick event and just use a submit event if you want, `$("#myform").submit(function(){ $("#jsonvalue").val(JSON.stringify({"userdata":$('#user_data').val()}));});` by not returning false, it will continue to submit with the updated hidden input value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add a hidden input field with the json value, like this -

```
function submitform() {
    var url = '/users/' + $('#user_id').val();
    $('#myform').attr('action', url);
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "userdata": $('#user_data').val()
    })
    $('<input type="hidden" name="json"/>').val(data).appendTo('#myform');
    $("#myform").submit();
}
```

You can access your json using `json` parameter (*name of hidden input*)

Comment: This is all great and all, but how to than parse the json from the PHP server-side, I've tried using `json_decode($_POST['json'])` but it returns `NULL` value here. I can not change entire form to JSON as there are other fields in the form that need to be passed via the regular form post way.