# Is there any way to do a non-Ajax form submission with pure JSON data, with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, http-post

I was able to find [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116532/post-json-data-from-form-without-ajax), which offered a consolation prize that I may end up using: if you want to feed JSON to the server on a POST whole page update, you are able to assign the JSON content to a (perhaps hidden) input.

However, I wanted to check in as far as reality checks go. jQuery has, as a basic and straightforward feature to offer, the ability to call `jQuery.ajax()` with, as one major option, a JSON string sent as the query string. And it's almost a non-option to fail to provide this functionality; people have come to expect to be able to provide pure-JSON data either way including contexts unrelated to the web and between two non-JavaScript endpoints.

Is there a non-workaround way now to do a page submit with the query string being neither more nor less than whatever JSON string encodes what the developer is sending?

Comment: Only other way is pass data to GET url query string but not with a form. Not really clear what specific problem is

Comment: You could serialize the form's values.

Comment: Put differently: I can easily make a FORM that, on submission, submits a query string like `field1=value1&field2=value2`. What I don't see, *as an option without submitting to GET's short character limit*, is a way to submit a form via POST where, as is a very common scenario with jQuery Ajax, the query string is JSON like `{"a":["first","second"],"b":9.80665}`, etc. Ajax has had a JSON string sent as the query string for ages. Is an equivalent option available with a Web 1.0 whole page update?

Comment: Using POST and default form process the only way is to set the json as value of an input...or use ajax

Comment: Can you perhaps `stringify` your data, before submitting? Then `JSON.parse()` server-side.